# Retrieve all images directories in android

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-file, subdirectory, android-gridlayout

I have tried this to get directories and load images from them but it is very slow to load images and when camera is selected it crashed after some time...

< -------- Code to get directories and images from them ------- >

```
public static ArrayList<String> getImageBuckets(Context mContext){
    ArrayList<String> buckets = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String [] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null){
        File file;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String bucketPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));
            String fisrtImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]));
            file = new File(fisrtImage);
            if (file.exists() && !buckets.contains(bucketPath)) {
                buckets.add(bucketPath);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return buckets;
}


public static ArrayList<String> getImagesByBucket(Context mContext , @NonNull String bucketPath){

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String [] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME+" =?";
    String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED+" DESC";

    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection,new String[]{bucketPath}, orderBy);

    if(cursor != null){
        File file;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));
            file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists() && !images.contains(path)) {
                images.add(path);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return images;
}
```

<  ---------- Here is adapter and method to select directory --------->

```
        <--------------------Adapter------------------>


public class GridImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int layoutResource;
    private String mAppend;
    private ArrayList<String> imgURLs;

    public GridImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, String append, ArrayList<String> imgURLs) {
        super(context, layoutResource, imgURLs);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mContext = context;
        this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
        mAppend = append;
        this.imgURLs = imgURLs;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imgURLs.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridImageProgressbar);
            holder.image = (SquareImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridImageView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final String imgURL = getItem(position);

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mAppend + imgURL).error(R.drawable.ic_person).into(holder.image, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (holder.mProgressBar != null) {
                    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mAppend + imgURL).into(holder.image);
                    holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                if (holder.mProgressBar != null) {
                    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mAppend + imgURL).into(holder.image);
                    holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        SquareImageView image;
        ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    }
}
```

< -------------- Method to set grid view ----------->

```
private void Directory() {

    directories = FileSearch.getImageBuckets(getActivity());

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
            ,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item ,directories);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    directorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    directorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemSelected: selected" + directories.get(position));

            setGridView(directories.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

private void setGridView(String selectedDir){
    Log.d(TAG, "setGridView: Dir chosen");
    final ArrayList<String> imageURL = FileSearch.getImagesByBucket(getActivity() ,selectedDir);

    int gridWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int imageWidth = gridWidth/NUM_GRID_COLOUMN;
    gridView.setColumnWidth(imageWidth);

    GridImageAdapter adapter = new GridImageAdapter(getActivity() , R.layout.grid_image_layout ,append , imageURL);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I didn't went thorugh your code, all I can suggest is using some image loading library to load a fixed size of images, according to view dimensions.
Also while using picasso we can stop image download when list is scrolling and only start it when there is no scrolling, refer this link: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-getting-started-simple-loading

Comment: But why app crash only when try to load image from camera directory and also slow in loading images from it?

Comment: If your app is crashing I suggest you post the error log. And slow loading of images is usually because you try to load more pixels than required

Comment: there is nothing shown in logcat ..